# Cryptic error message when passing const parameters as arguments

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, parameter-passing

So I am writing an implementation of doubly linked lists. This the constructor of the class implementing individual nodes:

```
DNode::DNode(const int a_key, const DNode* a_prev, const DNode* a_next) 
    : key(a_key), prev(a_prev), next(a_next) {}
```

The reason I wrote `const int a_key, const DNode* a_prev, const DNode* a_next` is because the constructor has no reason to modify them. So I just want to protect myself from doing any unwanted modifications inside the constructor. Is this a good thing to do?

Compilation outputs the following error:

> dnode.cpp:6:89: error: cannot initialize a member subobject of type
>   'DNode *' with an lvalue of type 'const DNode *' DNode::DNode( const
>   int a_key, const DNode* a_prev, const DNode* a_next ) : key(a_key),
>   prev(a_prev), next(a_next) {}
>
> dnode.cpp:6:103: error: cannot initialize a member
>   subobject of type 'DNode *' with an lvalue of type 'const DNode *'
>   DNode::DNode( const int a_key, const DNode* a_prev, const DNode*
>   a_next ) : key(a_key), prev(a_prev), next(a_next) {}

I don't understand the error message. `DNode*` is a pointer type, not an lvalue. Any help is welcome.

**=== EDIT ===**

I modified my code into the following.

dnode.h

```
class DNode {

 public:

  //
  DNode( const int a_key, const DNode& a_prev, const DNode& a_next );

  //
  int get_key() const;
  DNode* get_prev() const;
  DNode* get_next() const;

  //
  void set_key( const int a_key );
  void set_prev( const DNode& a_prev );
  void set_next( const DNode& a_next );

  //
 private:

  int key;
  DNode* prev;
  DNode* next;

};
```

dnode.cpp

```
//
DNode::DNode( const int a_key, const DNode& a_prev, const DNode& a_next ) 
: key(a_key), prev(&a_prev), next(&a_next) {}

//
int DNode::get_key() const { return key; }
DNode* DNode::get_prev() const { return prev; }
DNode* DNode::get_next() const { return next; }

//
void DNode::set_key( const int a_key ) { key = a_key; }
void DNode::set_prev( const DNode& a_prev ) { prev = &a_prev; }
void DNode::set_next( const DNode& a_next ) { next = &a_next; }
```

I get the following error message

> dnode.cpp:6:89: error: cannot initialize a member subobject of type
>   'DNode *' with an rvalue of type 'const DNode *' DNode::DNode( const
>   int a_key, const DNode& a_prev, const DNode& a_next ) : key(a_key),
>   prev(&a_prev), next(&a_next) {}
>
> dnode.cpp:6:104: error: cannot initialize a member
>   subobject of type 'DNode *' with an rvalue of type 'const DNode *'
>   DNode::DNode( const int a_key, const DNode& a_prev, const DNode&
>   a_next ) : key(a_key), prev(&a_prev), next(&a_next) {}
>
> > dnode.cpp:15:52: error: assigning to 'DNode *' from
> >     incompatible type 'const DNode *' void DNode::set_prev( const DNode&
> >     a_prev ) { prev = &a_prev; }
>
> dnode.cpp:16:52: error: assigning to 'DNode *' from incompatible type
>   'const DNode *' void DNode::set_next( const DNode& a_next ) { next =
>   &a_next; }

Once again, the reason I am writing `const DNode& a_prev` in the constructor's parameter list is because I want to prevent `a_prev` from being modified by the constructor (but I don't care if it is modified outside). But since it's not working, I might have misunderstood the usage of `const` in this context.

Comment: How do you pass arguments to the constructor?

Comment: I've just edited your constructor code, breaking it into two different lines, to make it more readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think inside your class you have data members (that you haven't showed), defined like:

```
DNode* prev;
DNode* next;
```

In the constructor, you have `const DNode*` parameters (`a_prev` and `a_next`):

```
DNode::DNode(const int a_key, const DNode* a_prev, const DNode* a_next) 
   : key(a_key), prev(a_prev), next(a_next) {}
```

`const DNode*` parameters mean that you have a pointer to a `DNode` that is **const**, i.e. that `DNode` pointed to can't be modified.
But you want to assign it to `DNode*` data members, that are non-`const` (i.e. that `DNode` pointed to *can* be modified).
You can't assign something that is constrained as `const` (i.e can't be modified), to something that is non-`const` (i.e. it can be modified).

The following code should work:

```
// Remove 'const' from the pointers!
DNode::DNode(const int a_key, DNode* a_prev, DNode* a_next) 
  : key(a_key), prev(a_prev), next(a_next) {}
```

If you want to use this "`const` on input parameters" style, like `const int a_key`, you should put `const` between the pointer symbol (`*`) and the parameter name, e.g.

```
// Proper placing of 'const'
DNode::DNode(const int a_key, DNode* const a_prev, DNode* const a_next) 
  : key(a_key), prev(a_prev), next(a_next) {}
```

This means that `a_prev` and `a_next` can't be reassigned to point to other data; but they do point to something that *can* be modified (a `DNode*`).

Comment: Thanks. It did compile when removing `const` from the parameters. I think I misunderstood the meaning of `const` in this context. I thought it meant "that parameter should not be modified by the function call". But actually it seems to mean "that parameter is a `const` object and should not be modified ever, independently of function calls". Is this correct?

Comment: @jfk916: It depends on where you put the `const`. If you have `const X* p`, it means that the instance of `X` pointed to is `const`, but `p` can be modified to e.g. pointing to something different. If you have `X * const p`, it means that `p` can't be modified (and can't point to something different), but `X` pointed to can be modified (is non-const). If you have `const X * const p`, both `p` and `X` are `const` and can't be modified.

Comment: @jfk916: If you find an answer helpful, consider voting +1.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to initialize a pointer to non-const object with a pointer to const object.
Maybe you wanted to pass const pointers to non-const objects? Then it would be `DNode* const a_prev`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `DNode` members `a_prev` and `a_next` are pointers to non-const objects.
A few options:

- Make these members into pointers to const objects
- Put the members on the stack, and pass in dereferenced arguments in the initialiser list in order to invoke the copy constructor.*
- Heap allocate the members in the constructor and pass the dereferenced arguments into the copy constructor calls.*
- Take non-const arguments for those pointers.

(*Looks like you're trying to write a doubly linked list though, in which case you don't want to hold copies of the other nodes, and it will be handy for previous and next nodes to able to be be null, leaving option 1 or 4.)